How to write the navigation for my kotlin android project?
So i need to write a navigation for my kotlin project:
here are my files for context:
Dao interface called UserDao:
`@Dao
interface UserDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insert(user: User)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM User")
    fun getAllUsers(): List<User>

}`


Model called User:
`@Entity(tableName = "User")
data class User(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @NotNull
    @ColumnInfo(name = "id")
    val id: Int = 0,
    val name: String,
    val surname: String,
    val email: String,
)`

repositories:
`interface BaseRepository<T> {
    suspend fun insert(t:T)
    suspend fun getAllUsers():List<T>
}`

second repository:
`class UserRepository(private val userDao: UserDao) : BaseRepository<User> {
    override suspend fun insert(t: User) =userDao.insert(t)
    override suspend fun getAllUsers(): List<User> = userDao.getAllUsers()
}`

AppCOntainer kt file:
`interface AppContainer{
    val userRepository: UserRepository
}
class AppDataContainer(private val context: Context): AppContainer{
    override val userRepository:UserRepository by lazy{
        UserRepository(UserDatabase.getDatabase(context).userDao())
    }
}`

UserDatabase data class:
`@Database(
    entities = [User::class],
    version = 1,
    exportSchema = false
)
abstract class UserDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun userDao(): UserDao
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var Instance : UserDatabase?=null

        fun getDatabase(context: Context): UserDatabase{
            return Instance?: synchronized(this){
                Room.databaseBuilder(context, UserDatabase::class.java, "UserDatabase").build().also { Instance=it }
            }
        }
    }
}`

my screen file:
`@Composable
fun HomeScreen(context: Context = LocalContext.current) {
    var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var surname by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var email by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var showMore by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var showSub by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var checkEmail by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }


    val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
    Column (
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.White)
            .fillMaxSize()
            .wrapContentWidth()
            .verticalScroll(scrollState),

        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top

    ){
        Box(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.Gray)) {
            Image(
                painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.picture),
                contentDescription = "",
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
        Text(text = "Jetpack Compose tutorial")
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(10.dp))
        Text(
            text = "Jetpack Compose.\n"
        )
        if(showMore == false) {
            Text(
                text = "...\n",
            )
        }
        if(showMore == true) {
            Text(
                text = "function name.\n",
            )
        }
        TextButton(onClick = { showMore = true }) {
            Text(
                color = Color.Blue,
                text = "Show more")
        }
        if(showSub==false)
            Button(onClick = { showSub=true }) {
            Text(text = "Subscribe")
        }

        if(showSub==true){
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            Text(text = "Please Enter your name and Surname")
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            TextField(value = name,
                onValueChange = { name = it },
                enabled = true,
                label = { Text(text = "name") },
                placeholder = { Text(text = "name") },
                isError = false,
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                    imeAction = ImeAction.Next))
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            TextField(value = surname,
                onValueChange = { surname = it },
                enabled = true,
                label = { Text(text = "surname") },
                placeholder = { Text(text = "surname") },
                isError = false,
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Text,
                    imeAction = ImeAction.Next))
            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
            TextField(
                value = email,
                onValueChange = { email = it },
                enabled = true,
                label = { Text(text = "email") },
                placeholder = { Text(text = "example@example.com") },
                isError = checkEmail,
                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                    keyboardType = KeyboardType.Email,
                    imeAction = ImeAction.Next
                ))
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(10.dp))
        if(showSub==true)
            Button(onClick = { checkEmail=!checkEmail(email)
               UserViewModel.addTask(Task(
                    title=title,
                    description=description))},
                modifier = Modifier.padding(30.dp)) {
                Text(text = "Subscribe")
            }

    }
}

fun checkEmail(email: String): Boolean {
    return Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()
}

@Preview(showBackground = false, uiMode = Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES)
@Composable
fun HomeScreenPreview() {
    MyApplication28Theme {
        HomeScreen()
    }
}`


i tried already implementing it but its not working, i keep getting errors. if someone has any ideas, would be helpful
UserViewModel:
`class UserViewModel (private val taskRepository: UserRepository) : ViewModel(){

    val tasks= mutableStateListOf<User>()

    init{
        viewModelScope.launch {
            tasks.addAll(taskRepository.getAllUsers())
        }
    }

    fun addUser(task: User){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            taskRepository.insert(task)
            tasks.add(task)
        }
    }
}`




You can find a best navigation article on medium. https://medium.com/@chiragthummar16/jetpack-compose-navigation-best-practices-beginners-239794217b61
